# Get text between html tags and Not-between html tags into List

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to use regex in c# to extract text entered through WYSIWYG editor. I am planning on using regex but Unable to do OR operator so i have an list of strings between html tags and Not-between html tags. The list is important to do post processing for Openxml - Presentation generation. This is what i have right now:

Thanks in advance.

```
string Pattern = "<.*?>(.*?)<\\/.*?>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(BankerBioRichtext, BoldPattern);
```

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <b>amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</b>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <i>ullamco laboris
nisi ut</i> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Trying an output:

```
li[0] lorem ipsum dolor sit
li[1] amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
li[2] , sed do eiusmod tempor................
```

Comment: The best solution with HTML is almost always to use a dedicated HTML parsing library such as HtmlAgilityPack, as opposed to parsing it yourself with Regex.

Comment: @John I will look through HTML parsing library and thanks for you advise. I have added regex i am using to get string between ANY html tags. I was not successful with doing OR condition on regex's and reached out to community. I have updated my question with regex now.

Comment: I don't see `Pattern` being used. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do exactly ?

Comment: You could always use split with this `<b\s*>(.*?)</b\s*>`

Comment: The best way to find good regex solutions is to use notepad++'s find. Just ctrl+f and attempt until it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really the best idea to do this task with regular expressions because of the time complexity, I guess. For example, we can check this expression,

```
(?<=>)([^<]*?)(?=<)|\b([^<>]{2,})
```

which is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqITbx/1/), if you wish to explore further, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lqITbx/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like, and how inefficient the process might be.

#### Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=>)([^<]*?)(?=<)|\b([^<>]{2,})";
        string input = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <b>amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</b>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <i>ullamco laboris
nisi ut</i> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/1DeIxf)